# Text Button Navigates but Button Doesn't - Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

My navigation links work well in **Text** (like button with background)
However, when it comes to **Button** it doesn't work same way, it's not navigating to **AddBook()** screen.

**Text Part (works well)**

```
NavigationView{
NavigationLink(destination: AddBook()){
                    Text("BOOK APP")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }}
```

**Button Part (Doesn't work)**

```
NavigationView{
NavigationLink(destination: AddBook()){
                
            Button{}
            label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                Text("Add Book")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .frame(width: .infinity, height:60, alignment: .top)
            }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NavigationLink` is like a `Button`, there is no need for a `Button` as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` action is overriding the `NavigationLink`.  The `NavigationLink` itself acts like a `Button`, therefore there is no need to use a button inside the `NavigationLink` label closure.